A Formula for the Norm in the Cyclotomic Field of Degree 5
So you all know and love, the Gaussian integers have a rather neat-looking norm: given $a+bi$, then $N(a+bi)=a^2 + b^2$. When it comes to the cyclotomic integers of degree 3, i.e. the domain $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ where $\zeta= \exp (i 2 \pi / 3)$, one finds the following neat formula: given $k+l \zeta + m \zeta^2$, then $N(k+l \zeta + m \zeta^2) = \frac{1}{2}[(k-l)^2+(k-m)^2+(l-m)^2]$.
I've been trying to come up with something in the same vein for the norm of cyclotomic integers of degree 5, i.e. in the domain $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ where $\zeta = \exp (i 2 \pi / 5)$. Given a cyclotomic integer $h + k \zeta + l \zeta^2 + m \zeta^3 + m \zeta^4$, the norm, when written out in full, is the massive expression:
$$h^4 - h^3 k + h^2 k^2 - h k^3 + k^4 - h^3 l + 2 h^2 k l - 3 h k^2 l - 
 k^3 l + h^2 l^2 + 2 h k l^2 + k^2 l^2 - h l^3 - k l^3 + l^4 - 
 h^3 m + 2 h^2 k m + 2 h k^2 m - k^3 m - 3 h^2 l m - h k l m + 
 2 k^2 l m + 2 h l^2 m - 3 k l^2 m - l^3 m + h^2 m^2 - 3 h k m^2 + 
 k^2 m^2 + 2 h l m^2 + 2 k l m^2 + l^2 m^2 - h m^3 - k m^3 - 
 l m^3 + m^4 - h^3 n - 3 h^2 k n + 2 h k^2 n - k^3 n + 2 h^2 l n - 
 h k l n + 2 k^2 l n - 3 h l^2 n + 2 k l^2 n - l^3 n + 2 h^2 m n - 
 h k m n - 3 k^2 m n - h l m n - k l m n + 2 l^2 m n + 2 h m^2 n + 
 2 k m^2 n - 3 l m^2 n - m^3 n + h^2 n^2 + 2 h k n^2 + k^2 n^2 + 
 2 h l n^2 - 3 k l n^2 + l^2 n^2 - 3 h m n^2 + 2 k m n^2 + 
 2 l m n^2 + m^2 n^2 - h n^3 - k n^3 - l n^3 - m n^3 + n^4 .$$
I've been spending now two-three hours trying to properly simplify this mess, but I keep coming up with nothing. Using Mathematica, I have been able to establish a notion of "sort of" what such a formula (if it exists) should look like, since:

One feels that a formula like this should be a "standard result", something that one should be able to easily find listed in some table in a textbook somewhere, but so far, I've discovered nothing. Anyone have anything they can offer to help me in this matter?

Is your $\alpha$ the same thing as your $,\zeta,?;$  For $3$, why don’t you just say $N\left(a+b,\zeta_3\right)=a^2+ab+b^2$?

Oh, it just didn't occur to me at the time when I was computing the norm to use the identity $1+\zeta_3+\zeta_3^2=0$ to reduce the equation down to the form $a+b \zeta_3$. :P

Is your question "why haven't I seen this formula before?" If so, I think there is a straight-forward answer: It is neither useful nor enlightening, and it is something most people would be able to work out themselves.
One could seek formulas for any cyclotomic field, what makes the fifth special?

Not quite, my question is, "what is the formula?" Believe it or not, if such a formula exists, it'll actually be useful for my purposes, and so if most people would be able to work it out themselves, I'd be most happy to see it! :)

Correction to my above comment:  should have been $a^2-ab+b^2$.   Also, cf. this question

I will say some words. We do not have a question with a clear target, for instance a formula or a property to be shown. The soft question is of the type "is there any related structure"? (...or at least so i would restate it, so that we have a target.)
The related structure that i see is solving equations of a given degree.

To solve the equation of degree two, which is quickly brought from the general form to the special form $x^2+A=0$ we only have to write $-A$ as a square.
After doing so, we have to deal with an equation of the shape $x^2-a^2=0$. So we reduce to the case of a "radical extension" of degree two. And the formula that has to be used in this case is:
$$
(x-a)(x+a)=0\ .
$$
Now this is "not a norm", and a quite different story, but if we would now work algebraically over some/any quadratic field $\Bbb Q(u)$ over $\Bbb Q$, $u=\sqrt D$, for instance $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 7)$, or $\Bbb Q(\sqrt {-1})$, then computing the norm of some element of the shape $s+tu$ is
$$
N(s+tu)=(s+tu)(s-tu)\ ,
$$
and we use the formula for $(x-a)(x+a)$, which is "known", and "familiar", so a parallel to it, if there is one, may be give the direction of an answer.
So the applied formula is, let us record it:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad
(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-B^2\ .
\qquad}
$$
To solve the equation of degree three, which is quickly brought from the general form to the special form $x^3+px+q=0$, we would also like to factorize! But how to factorize?! This is a first impediment. The second one is the fact that we want to reduce the complexity of the equation to "solutions by radicals" again. So an expression like $u=\sqrt[3]D$ is natural to appear, and we do want to let it happen so. For (new) reasons, we also need to adjoin the primitive root of the unit, $\zeta=\zeta_3$. Now going in the direction of solving the equation, we expect the roots to be three, and furthermore to be of the shape
$$
\begin{aligned}
a+bu+cu^2&=a+b\sqrt[3]D+c\sqrt[3]{D^2}\ , 
\\
a+b\zeta u+c\zeta^2 u^2&=a+b\zeta\sqrt[3]D+c\zeta^2\sqrt[3]{D^2}\ , 
\\
a+b\zeta^2 u+c\zeta u^2&=a+b\zeta^2\sqrt[3]D+c\zeta\sqrt[3]{D^2}\ , 
\end{aligned}
$$
where the first expression is "natural" for algebraic reasons (we work in the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]D)$), and the other two become natural for reasons of Galois symmetries (replace $\sqrt[3]D$ from the first expression by
$\zeta\sqrt[3]D$, respectively
$\zeta^2\sqrt[3]D$, Galois substitutions). The Galois group may be in general more complicated, but the "minimal complication" arises when these are the only conjugates we need. So we are naturally going to build
$$
(x-(a+bu+cu^2))
(x-(a+b\zeta u+c\zeta^2 u^2))
(x-(a+b\zeta^2 u+c\zeta u^2))
\ .
$$
We then make computations. The OP has a similar situation, the expression
$k+l\zeta+m\zeta^2$, is considered and we take the norm w.r.t. the extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta):\Bbb Q$. The last two factors only are then needed. But from the point of view of a radical extension, so after twisting $l,m$ by $\sqrt[3]D$, and $\sqrt[3]{D^2}$, it is also natural to consider a third factor, $k+l+m$. It is not part of computing the norm for $k+l\zeta+m\zeta^2$, but becomes a part of such a computation if we also "invent $D$" in the picture. Making it short, consider not the three factors above. Use the letters $A,B,C$ for $(x-a),-bu,-cu^2$. Then we have the following formula:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\qquad
(A+B+C)
(A+B\zeta+C\zeta^2)(A+B\zeta^2+C\zeta)
=A^3 + B^3 + C^3 - 3ABC\ .
\qquad}
$$
Arguably, the R.H.S. is "not so complicated". In fact it is symmetric, as the product we started with is so w.r.t. the symmetry which multiplies simultaneously $A,B,C$ by $\zeta$, and/or by their cyclic permutations. Recall that $B,C$ were containing $u=\sqrt[3]D$ (to some powers). The final expressions is so that it "lives over the integers". For instance, if we use a $\Bbb Z/3$-grading of monomials in $A,B,C$, so that they have in order degrees $0,1,2$ modulo three (as the $u$ appear in $A,B,C$ in terms of $a,b,c$), then finally the remained monomials are those and only those of usual degree three, and neutral (zero) w.r.t. the $\Bbb Z/3$-grading.
From this perspective, and in order to make things short now, we consider the case of the cyclotomic field of order five, $\zeta$ is a primitive root of order five, and we consider an equation of degree five. Not every such equation can be solved by radicals. But when it can be solved, we again expect a case of "minimal complication". We again consider
some radical value $u=\sqrt[5]D$, and consider only such "simple" equations with the roots of the shape
$$
\begin{aligned}
    a+bu+cu^2+du^3+eu^4
&=a+b\sqrt[5]D+c\sqrt[5]{D^2}+d\sqrt[5]{D^3}+e\sqrt[5]{D^4}\ , 
\\
    a+b\zeta u+c\zeta^2 u^2+d\zeta^3 u^3+e\zeta^4 u^4
&=a+b\zeta\sqrt[5]D+c\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{D^2}+d\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{D^3}+e\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{D^4}\ , 
\\
    a+b\zeta^2 u+c\zeta^4 u^2+d\zeta u^3+e\zeta^3 u^4
&=a+b\zeta^2\sqrt[5]D+c\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{D^2}+d\zeta\sqrt[5]{D^3}+e\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{D^4}\ , 
\\
    a+b\zeta^3 u+c\zeta u^2+d\zeta^4 u^3+e\zeta^2 u^4
&=a+b\zeta^3\sqrt[5]D+c\zeta\sqrt[5]{D^2}+d\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{D^3}+e\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{D^4}\ , 
\\
    a+b\zeta^4 u+c\zeta^3 u^2+d\zeta^2 u^3+e\zeta u^4
&=a+b\zeta^4\sqrt[5]D+c\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{D^2}+d\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{D^3}+e\zeta\sqrt[5]{D^4}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
As in the previous case we build the polynomial in $x$ with these roots, write $A,B,C,D,E$ for $x-a$, $-bu$, $-cu^2$, $-du^3$, $-eu^4$
(using "an other $D$"),
use the corresponding $u$-grading modulo five for monomials in $A,B,C,D,E$, and consider the expression:
$$
(A+B+C+D+E)\\
\cdot(A+B\zeta+C\zeta^2+D\zeta^3+E\zeta^4)\\
\cdot(A+B\zeta^2+C\zeta^4+D\zeta+E\zeta^3)\\
\cdot(A+B\zeta^3+C\zeta+D\zeta^4+E\zeta^2)\\
\cdot(A+B\zeta^4+C\zeta^3+D\zeta^2+E\zeta)\\
$$
which turns out to have the "simple" form:
$$
\sum A^5 
-5\sum B^3AC
-5\sum B^3DE
+5\sum A^2BC^2
+5\sum A^2B^2D
-5ABCDE\ .
$$
All sums are cyclic, thus introduce each five terms.

Arguably, this can be a manner to have a "known formula" for a related product...
